# PHP/Apache custom file type handling

Tags: php, apache

I'm wondering if it's possible to create custom file type handling for Apache that would be handled by a PHP file.

What I'm trying to accomplish, is to create a sort of custom `.phps` extension for reviewing code in the browser.

I'm using CodeMirror to display the code, but I'd like this process to be automated, as in I just change the `.php` extension to `.phps`, and some other `.php` file would handle that `.phps` file so I could inject the source code of that `.phps` file into a HTML file with CodeMirror.

I hope my goal is clear, I'm just wondering if it's at all possible.

**Edit:**

To clarify - I want to setup this rule to work from apache.conf, meaning that it would work across all the virtual hosts etc, not from a `.htaccess` file that would be required to be in every directory on the server.

I'm thinking this should work with `FilesMatch` within apache.conf, right now this is what I'm tinkering with:

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tools/code/?file=$1 [L]
</FilesMatch>
```

However I'm getting a `400 Bad Request` error. I'd like to build on top of something like this, so that Apache would handle `.phps` files from within it's configuration, and not have to use `.htaccess` files within every directory on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I figured this out, here's what I did:

In `apache.conf` I added this:

```
<FilesMatch "\.phps$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /tools/code/index.php [QSA,L]
</FilesMatch>
```

the `/tools/` directory is added as an alias

```
Alias /tools "C:/Web/httpdocs/tools/"
```

That's enough for using the defined `index.php` file as a "handler".

I used [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) to display the code. To load the `.phps` file for viewing within the editor, I added an invisible `<textarea>` element to the editor file with the source loaded into it:

```
<textarea id="code" style="display:none;">
    <?=file_get_contents(ltrim($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'], '/').$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);?>
</textarea>
```

I modified the initialization code to suit my needs:

```
<script>
    var editor = ace.edit('editor');
    editor.session.setMode('ace/mode/php');
    editor.setTheme('ace/theme/monokai');
    editor.setValue(document.getElementById('code').value);
    editor.gotoLine(1);
    editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
    editor.setReadOnly(true);
</script>
```

And voila, I have a more advanced way of viewing `.phps` files. Thanks for helping me get on track.

Comment: But if you use such a handler (the index.php file), then why do you have to declare an additional file type handler _at all_?

Comment: So that all `.phps` files are handled by that particular file in Apache throughout the server by default, without having to put in a complicated URL to view that file or using a `.htaccess` file in every directory I want the `.phps` file to be viewed in this way. To me it makes more sense than just using the provided `application/x-httpd-php-source` or `highlight_file()` function as the capabilities of using a code editor/viewer such as [Ace editor](https://ace.c9.io/) are far greater than just the default way of viewing `.phps` files.

Comment: If your question is about the `SetHandler application/x-httpd-php` rule, it's because otherwise Apache won't pass the file on to PHP for execution, but just prompt the file as a downloadable file.

Comment: But for a handler you only need a rewriting rule. You yourself define the location `/tools` for files that should be displayed as source files, if I understand this answer correct. If so, then that is all you need, a specific file type handler is not required on top of that, since in the rewriting you can define the handler to handle the file in whatever manner you want to.. But certainly there are alternatives, you found your solution, which is great!

Comment: About the "downloading" of files: no, you completely miss understood my answer. But all is fine.

Comment: So your question is about why I used `FilesMatch` instead of using a rewrite rule? As far as I understand, using rewrite rules in apache.conf isn't recommended as it would make every directory by default have `RewriteEngine On` thus initiating the rewrite module in cases where it isn't always needed, resulting in a slower server configuration, unless you specify which directory to apply the rule. I want this functionality server-wide without any per directory configration. That's why I used `FilesMatch` which is part of the Apache core, which is _supposed_ to be faster than the rewrite module.

Comment: No, my question was why you are registering an additional file type handler which is not required in my eyes. But as said before: all fine, you found your solution which serves you. Great!

Comment: Well I believe I answered why I chose this way. My goal - to replicate and **replace** the`.phps`functionality provided by `AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps` with something custom. Using a Rewrite rule in `apache.conf` as far as I understand could impact performance, using `.htaccess` files in every directory wouldn't be a replacement but a nuisance, using a url like `http://localhost/tools/viewcode.php?file=/directory/index.php` would also not replace the`.phps` functionality. So I'm not sure what other method I could've used to accomplish this as easily and effectively as I have.

Comment: 1. no one ever suggested `.htaccess` style files. Only you come back to that again and again. Why? 2. A rewrite rule application does not "slow the server down" more than an `Alias` directive. Why should it? 3. No one suggested you should use a URL like what you cite in your last comment. Did you even bother to read and understand other replies? and 4. this is the first time you say you want to _replace_ an existing file type handler, above you said you want to _create_ it. - I repeat: such file type definition is _not_ required here. A simple rewriting rule is all that is required.

Answer (score 2):

This certainly is possible, just take a look at the documentation. The way file type handlers work is well explained, take a look at the `AddType` command. However it is questionable if that is a good approach to what you describe as your goal, to visualize php source code. Wouldn't it be much easier and more elegant to use rewriting to hand over the requested file to a handler script which can "publish" it as you like?

For example you could use URLs like the following and internally rewrite it:

```
/source/path/to/file.php  => /path/to/handler.php?source=%2Fpath%2Fto%2Ffile.php
```

This could be done with apache rewriting module or in nginx using a general handler script:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/source/(.)*$ /path/to/handler.php?source=$1 [L,B]
```

That way you don't have to define some local file type and can name php files to be shown just as what they are: php files. I mean a php file is a php file. The file name extension should reflect type of what is contained in the file, not how it should be handled. That would mean you mingle separate layers of logic.

That is much more transparent to users in my view. Also it allows more fine grained control about what URLs to rewrite and maybe some additional arguments to specify, where desired.

---

Two notes for the above rewrite rule:

- you may have to enable Apaches `AllowEncodedSlashes` to `on`, depending on your existing server setup
- you have to change the syntax slightly if you want to use the rewriting rule inside `.htaccess` style files (you have to remove the leading slashes, depending on where you place that file). But in general such files should be avoided whenever possible: they are notoriously error prone, hard to debug, sometimes cause unexpected side effects and *really* slow the server down. So *if* you have access to the servers host configuration you should prefer to place such rules in there.

Comment: I don't see why this answer should collide with your additional information. The above suggest is, as written, specifically meant for the http servers host configuration and _not_ for `.htaccess` style files. You can simply create an file with the rules and include it in whatever host you want to use that service. Easy, clean and transparent. But there certainly are other solutions too, sure.

Comment: It's a pretty resilient approach, I agree with this answer

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in `httpd.conf` or `vhost.conf` and restart Apache server

```
<IfModule mime_module>
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .phps
</IfModule>
```

Or else you can use mod_rewrite

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Comment: @Matt If you want to add phps file entire domain then add my code in vhosts.conf or httpd.conf file